# How to write a letter of complaint after a UK visa refusal?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, ugandan-citizens

I am a Ugandan by nationality and a student. I have recently applied for a visit visa in the UK to see my cousins in the UK. I was refused the first time this year on the ground that I did not show my savings, income, and assets, and that I did not provide how I was supported in Uganda, despite placing my sponsor's financial statement. Given these reasons I decided to re-apply fulfilling the first refusal requirements by placing my bank statement with my savings, a letter from the university where I am studying at, my bank slips for payment of my tuition, my hostel slips as a student, my mother placed her bank statement, her land titles, and her payslips. All this evidence is showing that she is the one who supports me, my sponsor's financial statement which was included, as well. All this means we had satisfied the first refusal requirements which complies with v4.2 of appendix V: immigration rules for visitors, but still I was given yet another refusal which states:

> You have declared you are a student: supported by your mother and that you are single no children to support. You have stated that you propose to travel to the UK for the first time to see a friend.
>   I have taken into consideration that you presently claim to studying in Uganda. despite your university commitments I am not satisfied that your circumstances are such that leaving the UK would be an attractive prospect at the end of your visit and that therefore you intend to leave the UK.
>      Given the statements you have made and the documentary evidence you have presented to support your application I am not satisfied that your circumstances in Uganda, coupled with your reasons for wishing to travel to the UK, are such that you have shown your intentions are as stated or that you intend to leave the UK at the end of your proposed visit. I am therefore, not satisfied that you will leave the UK at the end of your proposed visit. your application for a visit visa has been refused under paragraph V4.2(a) V4.2(c)

All these are false accusations because I clearly indicated that I am visiting a family member, who is my cousin. For the second statement, I sent in my university documents, which show I am a student, and am in my final year with a semester left (which is in February to July 2016), and by the time I resume with my studies the UK visa would have expired. This was evidence I had no intentions to stay in the UK as suggested by them. I therefore laid my complaint to the manager of the company that is in charge of transporting our applications to Pretoria South Africa for assessment since our country is no longer in charge. He told me to write a complaint letter so that he could send it back to Pretoria, but I doubt whether my letter will be responded to. Any advice or idea on how to write the letter will really mean a lot.

Comment: Honestly, there doesn't seem to be much to complain about there, provided that the company you used is genuine and acually passed your application on. You were refused because the person reviewing your case wasn't covinced that you would leave at the end of your visa. They may be wrong, but you didn't provide strong enough reasons to convince them (for example, you could decide to not continue your studies). Sadly, it looks like visitng the UK is  not possible for you at the moment.

Comment: Providing a complaint template is easy enough to do, I have written dozens of them. But depending upon the degree of relationship with your UK host, it may make more sense if they lodge the complaint from within the UK. What relationship is your UK host to you?

Comment: E.g., related through whom. Are they settled in the UK? Are they working?  Try to give some indication about your proposed host...

Comment: First time you said cousins, second time you said friend. That would have raised red flags. Most African countries are considered as high risk of fraudulent immigration. They aren't accusing you, they are simply laying down the reasons for refusal. Preferably you could have showed family connections in Uganda rather than only monetary

Comment: @DumbCoder the second mention as "friend" is in quoting the refusal letter, and that is one of the points about which Faith wishes to complain.

Comment: "Cousins" do not qualify as family members. And the word 'cousin' itself can have different meanings

Comment: "All these are false accusations" ... you mean that "you have declared you are a student" is a false accusation, and that "supported by your mother" is a false accusation? You seem to be making those claims yourself in your question here; how do they become "false accusations" by being repeated by the ECO? If you think that **some** of the statements in the refusal letter are false, you should point out which ones you're talking about, not just say "all", which is plainly wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The thing that is lacking from your application seems to be compelling reasons to return to Uganda. Students drop out of universities at the drop of a hat if they find something better to do, so you need to prove that you have a reason to return and continue your studies. Simply being enrolled is not enough.

Is your tuition 100% financed by your mother or do you have any scholarships?  Since many scholarships end if you drop out, that might be a point in your favor.

Are you close to graduating? Are you involved with any projects, like thesis research towards a degree? Do you do any work at the university, such as student assistant to a professor for their research or classes?  Documenting any of these might be a point in your favor.

Of course school is not the only reason accepted, family involvement helps too, such as if you assist with care giving for an elderly or sick family member.  Or other contributions to your family that would motivate you to go home.

You are facing one of the main reasons for non-immigrant type visa denials, proving that you are motivated to go home.  And since motivation is not a cut & dry thing to document, it behooves you to gather anything and everything that points to your desire to return to Uganda and to your studies.

Don't mention what you feel are false accusations in the previous refusals, instead in your next letter simply point out all the reasons you have to go home at the end of your visit.